# Why transitionFromView... causes a delay in toView:?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview

I'm using transitionFromView:... UIView selector for interchange between two UIViewControllers in my application delegate and it works fine but UINavigationBar from my UINavigationController seems like has a different frame...

[image: issue in transition]

My Application Delegate is simple, I use a controller for download info, it has a delegate which informs that its action is over, in that momment I use UIView transitionFromView:... selector to animate the controllers interchange, and happens what I show you in the image. This problem also happen with the UIView from the UINavigationController too.

I have made some simple examples simulating the same and works fine, I believe that this problem is caused for the viewDidLoad selector in the UINavigationController rootController, am I correct? Or what else could being happen?

Comment: Which view controllers are you swapping? What is your situation such that you don't want to use `-[UIViewController presentModalViewController:animated:]` or `-[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:]`?

Comment: This is the way, I must call the download controller always, at the beginning of my application, so, for that reason the application delegate creates a instance of this controller and later I replace the window rootViewController with some animation, in this case a cross dissolve effect with the UIView transitionFromView:... selector